# Cannot calculate Markov chain steady state

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

currently I have a markov chain and need to calculate the steady state of the markov chain, but however the values does not converge.

I'm using python and numpy to calculate the transition state.

```
self.transition_state = np.array([[1/43, 2/43, 12/43, 0, 13/43, 5/43, 10/43],
                                [5/52, 8/52, 13/52, 0, 16/52, 8/52, 2/52],
                                [12/475, 16/475, 177/455, 2/475, 216/475, 40/475, 12/475],
                                [0, 0, 4/7, 0, 2/7, 1/7, 0],
                                [16/536, 13/536, 214/536, 5/536, 251/536, 26/536, 11/536],
                                [2/97, 5/97, 40/97, 0, 32/97, 12/97, 6/97],
                                [7/47, 8/47, 16/47, 0, 5/47, 5/47, 6/47]])
        
self.start_state = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

for i in range(500):

    self.start_state = np.dot(self.start_state, self.transition_state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix that you used is not a valid stochastic matrix.

I believe you made a typo at $(3,3)$-entry where it should be $\frac{177}{4\color{red}75}$.

```
import numpy as np

class solution():
    def __init__(self):
        self.transition_state = np.array([[1/43, 2/43, 12/43, 0, 13/43, 5/43, 10/43],
                                        [5/52, 8/52, 13/52, 0, 16/52, 8/52, 2/52],
                                        [12/475, 16/475, 177/475, 2/475, 216/475, 40/475, 12/475],
                                        [0, 0, 4/7, 0, 2/7, 1/7, 0],
                                        [16/536, 13/536, 214/536, 5/536, 251/536, 26/536, 11/536],
                                        [2/97, 5/97, 40/97, 0, 32/97, 12/97, 6/97],
                                        [7/47, 8/47, 16/47, 0, 5/47, 5/47, 6/47]])
        self.start_state = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
        for i in range(500):

            self.start_state = np.dot(self.start_state, self.transition_state)
            print(self.start_state)

solution()
```

and I obtain

```
[0.03420606 0.04137862 0.37865691 0.00556449 0.42559945 0.07719859
 0.03739588]
```

Comment: thanks. i was losing my mind over this